# how to save list<object> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List<Data> datas = [];

Future<List<Data>> getData() async {
final response =
  await http.get('https://iptv-org.github.io/iptv/index.country.m3u');
final m3u = await M3uParser.parse(response.body);

for (final entry in m3u) {
Data data = Data(entry.title, entry.attributes['tvg-logo'], entry.link,
    entry.attributes['tvg-language'], 'false');
datas.add(data);
}

return datas;
}


class Data {
String title;
String logo;
String url;
String language;
String isFavorite = 'false';

Data(this.title, this.logo, this.url, this.language, this.isFavorite);
}
```

Everytime I get the data from the url, then how I gonna save the list of Data object? Can I save the data using sharedPref?

Answer (score 0):

for complicated data its recommended to use the database. you can use [SqfLite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) package as a database. but u can also use shared Preferences too. for creating Model use [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/) it will create your model with several useful methods such as toJson and fromJson. it will also generate fromRawJson and toRawJson. these two methods work with String. you can convert your model to string and stored to SharedPreferences and when you need it again take it and convert it to model.